# How to write join query in hql?

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I have two beans as `VehicleRegisterBean` and `GroupDetails`. I didnt made relation between these two tables, but in `VehicleRegisterBean` I have `groupid` and in `GroupDetails` I have `groupid` and `groupname`. now I want details from both the tables. So I am trying inner join as follow ,

```
Select vb.vehicle_no,gd.groupname from VehicleRegisterBean as vb INNER JOIN GroupDetails as gd on  vb.group_id=gd.groupid where vb.region='dvg'
```

I am trying this for generating reports. I am getting error as,

`Error:unexpected tocken near line1 and column 122`

How can I solve this can anyone help me in this.?

Comment: post the complete stacktrace of error

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont if this works with hql, but you could try this:

```
Select vb.vehicle_no,gd.groupname 
from VehicleRegisterBean as vb, GroupDetails as gd
where vb.group_id=gd.groupid and vb.region='dvg'
```

Comment: it shows two `String` fields but I am not getting values.

Comment: hmm if there is an entry in VehicleRegisterBean whichs region-column has the value 'dgv' you should see something. If there is at least one such row but its not displayed, than I don't know what the problem could be, sorry